# Where to check the updated packages or new packages list in Launchpad?

Tags: launchpad

Where to check the updated packages or new packages list in launchpad

Comment: Just run Update Manager and click "check".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each upload to the Ubuntu archive is announced via a mailing list. They are also available via RSS.

- [Ubuntu Natty](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/natty-changes/) ([RSS](http://feeds.ubuntu-nl.org/NattyChanges))
- [Maverick](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/maverick-changes/) ([RSS](http://feeds.ubuntu-nl.org/MaverickChanges))

These are of course very high volume. Even after the release, all uploads to the proposed and security archives are announced.

[UbuntuUpdates.org](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/) is a third-party service that also tracks this sort of information, including for specific PPAs:

- [Updates for all releases, including PPAs](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/packages/latest_logs?utf8=%E2%9C%93&dist=all+releases&commit=Go&noppa=0)
- [List of PPAs tracked by UbuntuUpdates.org](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppas)

Also interesting is [Launchpad's build farm](https://launchpad.net/builders). Here you can see what packages are currently building in both PPAs and the official archives.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a PPA (Personal Package Archive) on your Software Sources then you need to run 
`sudo apt-get update`

Which update all of your packages. You should then be able to update via Synaptic or Software Center.

Comment: Sorry if i am not clear on this.I want to see the list on launchpad not on my PC which packages are updated in launchpad or uploaded to lauchpad